# Binary Exploitation - ASLR

Tags: memory, buffer-overflow, aslr

This is more so just a general question about how ASLR actually prevents Buffer Overflow. The statement I keep seeing is that it randomises the address space of the Stack and the excecutable. It then goes on to say that for this exploit to work the location of the excecutable and stack are needed. Thats the part I am getting confused on, all of the examples I have seen off Bufferoverflow dont trouble themselves with finding the location of these things.
This is one of the examples I looked at and all the other ones are pretty much the same, It doesnt  mention or do anything to do with the location of the Stack or excecutables.
Here is the link to the example in case the answer is there and I am not understanding something:
[https://www.coengoedegebure.com/buffer-overflow-attacks-explained/#:~:text=A%20buffer%20overflow%20occurs%20when,possibly%20taking%20over%20the%20machine](https://www.coengoedegebure.com/buffer-overflow-attacks-explained/#:%7E:text=A%20buffer%20overflow%20occurs%20when,possibly%20taking%20over%20the%20machine).

Sorry if this is a dumb question

```
#include <string.h>

void func(char *name)
{
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, name);
    printf("Welcome %s\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   func(argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so once we do a buffer overflow, we want to redirect control flow to something *that we know*.

Let's make this really simple and assume that the stack itself is executable. We could pop a reverse shell using [this](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/47008), for example. But, how do we run this shellcode, exactly?

So, what we want to do is overflow the buffer, change the return address on the stack to point to the stack itself (in particular, the offset of the stack where this shellcode exists, we could find these offsets using `gdb` for example).

But, how do we know where the stack is exactly?

A long time ago, before ASLR, the stack was always in a particular spot, so we could just use `gdb` (for example) to find where the stack was, and just change the return pointer to point to the stack (in particular, where our shellcode is).

But, with ASLR, we either need to brute force the stack position, along with NOP sleds (assuming we have enough room), or achieve address disclosure of the stack through another bug.

Comment: When talking about the location of the stack. Is it stored somewhere in the RAM and how does it work together with the CPU

Comment: Yes, it's stored somewhere in RAM. Virtually, in all linux distributions that I know of on x86_64, it is stored virtually somewhere in the `0x7f` offset. In order to find the physical address, you'd need kernel access, but you could use `vert_to_phys` to find the physical address.

Comment: Iirc virtual addresses are as follows:  
Page Map Level 4 -> Extended Page Directory -> Page Directory -> Page Table
Where the virtual address essentially describes (when its split up into bits) the indices into each of these virtual memory tables.

It's likely implementation specific based on the OS; see your OS's implementation of `vert_to_phys` for those details.

Comment: A good exercise is probably _actually writing_ a buffer overflow, say into a `void win() { printf("you won!\n"); }` style function without ASLR and then with ASLR with some address disclosure of the stack, with the help of `gdb`; this would probably illuminate a lot of the trouble you're facing.